# issues with z-index and multiple !important rules

Tags: css, z-index, sencha-touch, css-specificity

Has anyone ever encountered a case where a more specific `!important` declaration is not overwriting another `!important` declaration? Here is the base css:

```
.x-floating {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

And here is what I want to use to override the z-index:

```
.x-msgbox.x-floating {
  z-index: 10001 !important;
}
```

When I inspect via the Chrome (or Safari) debugger on Windows, I see the `.x-msgbox.x-floating` declaration being overwritten (crossed out), and the `x-floating` declaration being active. This goes against what I know of css specificity, and what I expect from [simplified tests](http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/Vpb6M/2/).

**Example code:**

Since I'm using Sencha, this will only work in Chrome or Safari, but here's a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/yFnGU/2/) (perhaps not kosher to hotlink Sencha's source, but this'll never get enough views for it to matter at all). To run the test, click the "choose date" button, then spin one of the wheels by dragging. A message box will appear. Compare the message box with the date picker (the top level elements of each — children of the body; another way to do it is to look for elements with class `x-floating`).

Comment: Clicking "choose date" froze my browser...

Comment: Did you use Chrome or Safari?

Comment: Huh. I'm running the beta channel (Chrome 11.0.696.50), not dev. Might be worth filing a bug report, but it's probably due to the instability of the dev channel -- Sencha is relatively well tested, and the example code is pretty simple. Safari 5.0.4 on Windows doesn't choke on it either.

Comment: This is truly bizarre, especially the jsFiddle demo.  Not only is your selector more specific, it is an on-page style (that's how jsFiddle handles css).  Along with `!important`, either of those facts individually should override the style.  Further, examining element.style in Chrome dev tools indicates that there is no inline style being applied.  I suppose it's possible that you have stumbled upon a genuine webkit bug.

Comment: @Ender: I'd be more comfortable saying it's a webkit bug if I could produce a simple test case, but it certainly does seem possible. Yet another reason to avoid the use of `!important`. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Default position is static. In static position can´t use z-index.

```css
.x-msgbox.x-floating {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10001 !important;
}
```

Comment: The `.x-floating` declaration applies `position: absolute` to the element. It's not `position: static`.

Comment: You are awesome dude, been looking for complex solutions but man this is just perfect

Answer (score 0):

`!important` sets the highest priority for that css

why `.x-msgbox.x-floating`? and not `.x-msgbox` only.

the first time you give `.x-floating` the highest priority, so the next time there is important (`z-inbdex.10001`) this time it is ignored.

the first `!important` can be deleted

why not creating a new class and overwriting it again directly with the new value?

and `x_msgbox` would maybe also better

Comment: If giving `x-floating` the "highest priority" makes it ignore the next `!important` property, then my simplified test shouldn't result in the text being blue. I would be more inclined to trust your answer if you could explain those results as well, and point to documentation that supports your claims. As it is, I suspect you didn't fully understand the question.

Comment: see here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules  only the property z-index has the highest attribute    the text is blue because the value is overwritten, see it in firebug  should be logical, if you give it also for color in x-floating the !important rule then the color is right  you are overwriting x-floating with your code normally  you should give an element different classes and not only one: class="x-floating x-msgbox" and not only one   so your second class should only be x-msgbos in the css, it automtically overwrites the z-index property